# List cherry picking slicing method

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

It's fairly simple to articulate problem, but I'm not 100% sure that I have my lingo right. Nonetheless, conceptually "cherry picking" is suitable to describe the slice I have in mind. This is because I simply want to access (cherry pick from all elements) two distant elements of a list. I tried this:

```
my_list[2,7]
```

So I was expecting it to return only 2 elements, but instead I got the error:

> list indices must be integers, not tuples.

I searched this error, but I found it was actually a very general error and none of the problems that instigated this error were actually for my type of problem.

I suppose I could extract the elements 1 at a time and then merge them, but my gut tells me there is a more "*pythonic*" way about this.

Also a slightly more complicated form of this problem I ran into was building a new list from an existing list of lists:

```
new_list = []
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    new_list.append(my_list[i][2,7])
```

Comment: extract the elements one at a time. no need to complicate such a simple and fast operation.

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard True maybe in hindsight that example was too simple. I have included another example of the same problem I ran into.

Comment: use slicing with steps if I am understanding? `my_list[2,8,5]`

Comment: @aws_apprentice That's what I thought I should do too, but I'm puzzled why I got the list indices error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally I would just use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) for this:

```
>>> my_list = list(range(10))
>>> import operator
>>> list(operator.itemgetter(2, 7)(my_list))
[2, 7]
```

It also allows getting an arbitrary amount of list elements by their indices.

---

However you can always use NumPy (that's an external package) and it's integer slicing for this (but it won't work for normal Python `list`s, just for NumPy arrays):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> my_arr = np.array(my_list)
>>> my_arr[[2, 7]]
array([2, 7])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [1]: myList = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
In [2]: myList[2:8:5]
Out[2]: [2, 7]
```

`myList[start:end:stride]`

Hope this helps.